# Name for regular polytope vertex embedding

Tags: polytopes

What I mean by that is using some vertices of a regular polytope to construct another, such as a tetrahedron in a hexahedron. I've thought about this topic, but I do not know its name, if it has any.

Comment: No idea about the name but for polyhedron, there is [Conway polyhedron notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polyhedron_notation) which is used to describe polyhedron based on a seed polyhedron modified by various prefix operations. Take a look and see whether this is the sort of stuff you are after.

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, but an interesting read nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for **facetings**. A facet of a poltope is the span of any subset of the vertex set of a polytope (as such some afine subspace) intersected with the given polytope - or, alternatively, the convex hull of those vertices. The most prominent facets of a d-dimensional polytope surely are its d-1-dimensional facets. Those are all the boundary faces, but also several (vertex defined) cross-sections. A faceting (polytope) then is any dihedral polytope, which can be obtained from such (prominent) facets. - As such faceting is the dual concept of stellation. Both concepts will produce several non-convex polytopes from a given convex starting polytope.

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

To add to Richard's answer, faceting (or facetting) is the reciprocal process of stellation. If you begin with polyhedron $P$ and stellate it to say $S$, then dualise the stellation in the conventional way, by reciprocation in a concentric sphere, the result $S^*$ will be a facetting of $P^*$, the dual of $P$.

So, for example, the facettings of the regular dodecahedron are duals of the stellated icosahedra.

Coxeter briefly defines faceting and its reciprocal relation to stellation in his classic *Regular Polytopes*.

James Bridge studied some facetings of the regular dodecahedron: Bridge, N. J.; "Facetting the dodecahedron", *Acta Crystallographica*, A30, 1974, pp. 548-552. ([pdf](http://www.attebregge.co.uk/polyhedra/Faceting.pdf))

I looked more systematically at the process involved and some simpler cases: Inchbald, G.; "Facetting Diagrams", *The Mathematical Gazette* 86, July 2002, p.p. 208-215. ([Web page](http://www.steelpillow.com/polyhedra/FacetingDiagrams/FacetingDiags.html)).